# Make Grid Column Scrollable

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, mudblazor

I am trying to make the first column of a grid scrollable:

```
<div class="mud-grid">        
    <div class="mud-grid-item mud-grid-item-xs-4" >
        <MudPaper>
        <h1>Filter criterias</h1>
        <div style="height: 100vh; overflow-y: auto;">
        @for(int i=0;i<35;i++){
        <div style="height:50px;border:1px solid;">  Filtering parameter #@i </div>
        }
        </div>
        </MudPaper>
        
    </div>
    <div class="mud-grid-item mud-grid-item-xs-8">
         <h1>Search Results</h1>
       @for(int i=0;i<1500;i++){
        <div style="height:50px;border:1px solid;">  Searc Results #@i </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

My implementation is here and a style of height: `100vh` is causing me some troubles

How can I set this value to automatically fit to the contents, even if I have 100 items on left side let the contents scroll completely till bottom allow the right section to stay as separate.

Answer (score -1):

your link doesnt load in for me.. so im a bit confused by your explenation but you could try a `width:fit-content` `overflow: auto`

overflow auto should result in a scroll bar appearing

Comment: I added the html to the question

Comment: made this donno what excactly u want..

`<div style="display:grid;grid-template-columns: auto auto auto; gap:1rem">
        <div style="width:30vw;height:10vh;overflow:auto">
            <div style="height:30vh;background:red"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:30vw;height:10vh;overflow:auto">
            <div style="height:30vh;background:red"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:30vw;height:10vh;overflow:auto">
            <div style="height:30vh;background:red"></div>
        </div>
    </div>`